# Law term that means that some document, paper or deal has no power in law

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Law term that means that some document, paper or deal has no power in law.

In Russian it is ничтожность (ничтожный договор), in Ukrainian it's нікчемність (нікчемний договір).

I've already asked it on [otvety.google.ru](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=29d8208ad7e805db&table=/otvety/user?userid=02804628469290596652&tab=wtmtoa) but I'm not sure that they are right.

Comment: illawgical. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase in UK/US law is [null and void](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/null+and+void) (see meaning 7).

> **null and void**: without legal force or effect; not valid: *This contract is null and void*.

Comment: That works in US too. You could also say "unenforceable".

Answer (score 17):

It is as Matt said *null and void*, but only if at some point it were legally valid. If it never was valid, you would describe it as *not legally binding*.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Equivalently, it is "a nullity", which works in English and is the literal translation of ничтожность.

Comment: *Non-binding* is another related option, as in *Congress passed a non-binding resolution opposing the practice* — i.e. Congress said they oppose the practice, but they didn't enact a law against it.

Answer (score 1):

In Standards documents, you'll find the term "non-normative," referring to passages which are merely explanatory and not to be considered part of the requirements specified by the text.